# if there other vibration method except use kSystemSoundID_Vibrate

Tags: ios

when iPhone has a incoming call , its vibration duration seems longer than invoke the method below:
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

how could i make the vibration duration as long as the iPhone incoming call .

I make a VoIP app, I want the single time vibration duration not too short...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method to achieve a longer vibration. But you could repeat the vibration permanently or with a timer and a little space between the vibrations.

Example of a timer based solution:

```
//start the vibration
NSTimer * vibrationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(vibrate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

//stop the vibration
[vibrationTimer invalidate];

-(void)vibrate{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you, but I don't want the little space between the two vibrations. I wanna the vibration same duration as the iPhone incoming call when my VoIP app has an incoming call.

Comment: I think this is not possible with current iOS APIs. What you could try is to repeat AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); immediately.

Comment: may be you are right. But I don't know why in apple's FaceTime, its vibration duration is longer than AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate).  maybe apple use their private api...

Comment: they definitely use private apis since you could also setup a custom vibration pattern in the setting